# overCls on a button does not work in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs4

My button

```
         [...]
         {
            xtype: 'button',
            overCls: 'test1',
            text: 'Référentiels',
            scale: 'medium',
            margin: '5 0 5 0',
            menu: [{
                text: 'Import',
                iconCls: 'importIcon',
                listeners: {
                    click: Import
                }
            }, {
                text: 'Consultation',
                iconCls: 'searchIcon',
                listeners: {
                    click: Consultation
                }
            }]
        }, [...]
```

and my CSS :

```
.test1
{
background: #ffb76b; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffb76b 0%, #ffa73d 50%, #ff7c00 51%, #ff7f04      100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffb76b),  color-stop(50%,#ffa73d), color-stop(51%,#ff7c00), color-stop(100%,#ff7f04)); /*   Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffb76b 0%,#ffa73d 50%,#ff7c00 51%,#ff7f04 100%);  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffb76b 0%,#ffa73d 50%,#ff7c00 51%,#ff7f04 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffb76b 0%,#ffa73d 50%,#ff7c00 51%,#ff7f04 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffb76b 0%,#ffa73d 50%,#ff7c00 51%,#ff7f04 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffb76b', endColorstr='#ff7f04',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

However, this is not working.
When the button is hovered, the CSS class is applied (I can see it in the console, x-btn-test1 instead of x-btn-over, etc) but it does not display on the button.

I tried with !important, same problem.

If I apply my css directly with

```
cls: test1
```

it's working.

Thanks for tips !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the framework **auto-appends the "x-"** prefix to your overCls class name; **add the prefix "x-"** to your class name, that should solve the problem, like this,

```
.x-test1 {....}
```

You can see a [working sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/overlordhammer/X7BeF/2/). Hope it helps.

Comment: I also find out another problem, maybe you could help me too. When adding an id to the button, the cls, overCls, etc are not applied.

Comment: Just tried [this modified example](http://jsfiddle.net/overlordhammer/WK2kj/) and setting an id doesn't seem to affect the result, may be you have some css rules for that specific id?

Comment: Hmhmh, seems like not, I'll try to find why. Thanks :)